# Unable to download Python on Windows System

Tags: python, windows, pip, windows-10, python-3.5

I'm having trouble getting python to work on my Windows 10 computer. I downloaded 3.5.2 off the website and ran the exe, but when I try to use

`pip install nltk`

So I copied and ran get-pip.py, but it still tells me "pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

`python -m pip install pip`

tells me that python is also not recognized. What should I do?

EDIT: Have tried reinstalling python, made sure the box to install pip was checked. Tried re-running the pip command in the Python command line (the one titled Python 3.5 (32-bit)) and it gave me an invalid syntax error on the word install.

Comment: Are you sure your python is set in your Windows Path?

Comment: Are you running your commands in a command prompt that is elevated?

Comment: I am running in the default command prompt. I am not sure of my path, I just downloaded and ran the exe.

Comment: @Sig can you type `python --version` and get a result? If so your path should be fine. Also, can you edit your question to include the results of what you are trying so we can better help...

Comment: Try using a python package such as pythonxy, will save you a lot of trouble installing packages: https://python-xy.github.io/downloads.html

Comment: @benjayhutton What GUI? Do you mean IDLE?

Frito, Command gave an error in both the regular command prompt and the Python command prompt

Answer (score 0):

When installing "the exe", make sure that you tick the checkbox labelled "Add Python 3.5 to PATH". That will solve the issue you mentionned.

Comment: @Sig Try referencing this link to add the python.exe to your path manually. http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/